# How to extract value from sub sampler request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. Please find below results tree-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FedVM.png)

I want to extract the session token from this sub sampler request and pass this token to my next request.
I used regular expression extracter. But it does not extract the value from request body. Please find my regular expression. I am not able to extract that token. Can anyone please let me know how to extract a value from request body in sub sampler ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDkhd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose `URL` in `Field to check`, as the session token is part of the URL and not headers

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `Field to Check` to **URL**
2. Remove `?` from your regular expression as you're using non-greedy match filter hence you will have only 1st character of the token and not the whole token

   [image]

More information:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://Regular%20Expressions)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)